# Can't get jQuery to work at all, please tell me what I'm doing wrong

Tags: jquery

I am supposed to be creating a game for my Javascript class and I am trying to create a checker game using jQuery. I just started adding jQuery and nothing has worked so far. It has been very frustrating.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#red1").hide();
});
```

```css
#checkerBoard {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 1000px;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}
.black {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
}
td {
    width: 2em;
    height: em;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>How to Play Checkers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>How to Play Checkers</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <!--add more-->
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>

        <p></p>
        <table id="checkerBoard">
            <thead><!--insert something--></thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr id="row1">
                <td class="red"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr id="row2">
                <td class="black"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/blackCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row3">

                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row4">

                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row5">

                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row6">
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
                <td class="black"></td>
                <td class="red"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row7">
                <td class="red"><img id="red1" src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row8">
                <td class="black"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="black"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
                <td class="red"><img src="images/redCheckerPiece.png" alt="red checker piece" /></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</div>

<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/css"></script><!--Move later?-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `script.js` included type shouldn't be `text/javascript" . and ensure jquery is loaded through chrome's network tab

Comment: `script.js` included type **should** (!) be `text/javascript` instead of `text/css`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you so much, that totally fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your jquery path is correct. JS type must be "text/javascript". It will also work if you remove type attribute. HTML5 supports it.

Comment: Is that a comment or an answer?

Comment: Not a reason... Contribute a little more. Only 15 points are needed to comment if my memory is good.

Comment: LOL @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: *"I don't have enough reputation to comment"* **does not mean that you should use an Answer instead**.  It means that you need to learn how to use the site, and when you are sufficiently experienced, you will be granted the [privilege](/help/privileges) of commenting.  Until then, please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/omutzak7/3/

Make sure that your linked script is the correct type.

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As you can see in the jsfiddle link the image is correctly hidden.